# Combine two rows SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables T1 and T2.
Table T1 is having Id (primary key), Level_type and State_type.
Table T2 is having Id(primary key), record_id (foreign key of Id column of table T1), Action_type (A1,A2,A3,A4), C_id, C_type( C1, C2), Created_at.

Table T1 -

| Id | Level_type | State_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L1 | S1 |
| 2 | L2 | S2 |

Table T2 -

| Id | record_id | action_type | c_Id | c_type | Created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | C | 111 | M | 08-Dec-2023 08.02.47 AM |
| 2 | 1 | C | 112 | M | 08-Dec-2023 08.03.47 AM |
| 3 | 1 | Ma | 113 | M | 08-Dec-2023 08.04.47 AM |
| 4 | 1 | C | 114 | C | 08-Dec-2023 08.08.47 AM |
| 5 | 1 | A | 115 | C | 08-Dec-2023 08.15.47 AM |
| 6 | 2 | C | 116 | M | 08-Dec-2023 09.02.47 AM |
| 7 | 2 | Ma | 117 | M | 08-Dec-2023 10.02.47 AM |
| 8 | 2 | A | 118 | C | 08-Dec-2023 11.02.47 AM |

I want the output to contain c_Id of c_type M and C with action_type as Ma and A and Created_at ordered descending. Below is the desired output -
In this MaId is the c_id where c_type is M and ChId is the c_id where c_type is C

| Id | Level_type | State_type | MaId | ChId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L1 | S1 | 113 | 115 |
| 2 | L2 | S2 | 117 | 118 |

Comment: You said you wanted the result set to be 'Created_at ordered descending', but your desired result set has increasing values for 'Created_at' - both for MaId and ChId

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       m.maid,
       m.chid
FROM   t2
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY record_id
         ORDER BY c_id
         MEASURES
           ma.c_id AS maid,
           a.c_id AS chid
         PATTERN ( Ma any_type*? A )
         DEFINE
           Ma AS action_type = 'Ma',
           A  AS action_type = 'A'
       ) m
       INNER JOIN t1
       ON m.record_id = t1.id
```

Or the `LEAD` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id,
       level_type,
       state_type,
       maid,
       chid
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.*,
         t2.action_type,
         t2.c_id AS maid,
         LEAD(CASE WHEN t2.action_type = 'A' THEN t2.c_id END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY t2.record_id
           ORDER BY t2.c_id
         ) AS chid
  FROM   t2
         INNER JOIN t1
         ON t2.record_id = t1.id
  WHERE  t2.action_type IN ('Ma', 'A')
)
WHERE  action_type = 'Ma';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T1 (Id, Level_type, State_type) AS
SELECT 1, 'L1', 'S1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'L2', 'S2' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T2 (Id, record_id, action_type, c_Id, c_type, Created_at) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'C',  111, 'M', DATE '2023-12-08' + INTERVAL '08:02:47' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'C',  112, 'M', DATE '2023-12-08' + INTERVAL '08:03:47' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'Ma', 113, 'M', DATE '2023-12-08' + INTERVAL '08:04:47' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 'C',  114, 'C', DATE '2023-12-08' + INTERVAL '08:08:47' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1, 'A',  115, 'C', DATE '2023-12-08' + INTERVAL '08:15:47' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2, 'C',  116, 'M', DATE '2023-12-08' + INTERVAL '09:02:47' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2, 'Ma', 117, 'M', DATE '2023-12-08' + INTERVAL '10:02:47' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 2, 'A',  118, 'C', DATE '2023-12-08' + INTERVAL '11:02:47' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | LEVEL_TYPE | STATE_TYPE | MAID | CHID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L1 | S1 | 113 | 115 |
| 2 | L2 | S2 | 117 | 118 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/khUDBVKr)

Comment: Your solution is great but it's complex to understand for beginner like me. Can it be made simpler to understand?

Comment: @Sakshi I've added another option using the `LEAD` analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggreagation` with `KEEP` clause as follows:

```
SELECT t1.id, T1.LEVEL_TYPE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.ACTION_TYPE= 'Ma' THEN T2.C_ID END)
         KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN T2.ACTION_TYPE= 'Ma' THEN CREATED_AT END DESC NULLS LAST) AS MAID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T2.ACTION_TYPE= 'A' THEN T2.C_ID END)
         KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN  T2.ACTION_TYPE= 'A' THEN CREATED_AT END DESC NULLS LAST) AS CHID
FROM   t2
       INNER JOIN t1
       ON t2.record_id = t1.id
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.LEVEL_TYPE
```

Comment: I tried the solution suggested by you. It works but if table is having more columns and I want those columns to be included in output, then I need to add it in GROUP BY clause. If I have 15 columns then all those 15 columns needs to be added in GROUP BY clause which is not appropriate. Is there any way to solve this issue?